# Toilet Leaking Underneath After Flushing

Tags: leak, toilet

My toilet, not long after flushing it, made popping noises and water flooded from underneath. There was very little water left in the bowl. I tried plunging the little bit of water lightly in off chance that could do something. Then flushed again. Again, water flooded out from underneath the toilet. The toilet was installed about 6 years ago and has had light use. No issues until now. It does not rock - it's super solid. The bolts seem tight from checking with my fingers. Could it be the wax ring that needs replacing? If so, I found instructions on here how to do it. I'm no pro but can read instructions, so I hope I can do it myself, even though I'm not a guy. I also have to be sure I can do any lifting of it if it's not super heavy.

Comment: The most likely cause is the wax ring or seal  has failed. The flange could be broken as well. You need to remove the toilet to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it might be the wax ring.  I highly recommend YouTube as a resource for learning about toilet repairs.  My first DIY toilet replacement was intimidating and the videos helped get me through it.

One thing I've learned though, don't bother ever trying to modify a wax ring no matter what you hear online.
Wax rings are cheap and easy to find.  Buy one of each if you don't know which one you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

A toilet can be heavy ( relatively).  It is one of the heaviest items involved in home renovation.  If you cannot lift at least 70 Pounds, I recommend calling a plumber. This will be the determining factor in whether you can do the repair yourself, or not.

As mentioned by others, the most likely cause of the problem is the seal between the toilet and the toilet flange on the floor.  There can also be a crack in the flange or the toilet itself. That would require another set of repair instructions.

Since this is an issue that can cause further problems in your home from the leaking water, you should call a plumber to get the issue fixed properly.

Again, the weight of the toilet will determine if you can move forward with a self repair. It is essential that the person doing the repair be able to lift **AND** control the placement of the toilet.

My recommendation is call a plumber.